# Cannot resize window of desktop app on WSL2 through X server

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, x-server

Running a Qt desktop app on WSL2 through X server on Windows 10, I cannot drag, resize or maximize the window. I tested with VcXsrv, Xming and MobaXterm. I also tested with Ubuntu 20.04 and 22.04. The issue is always there.

Comment: Thanks for reposting over here rather than Stack Overflow, at least!  And Welcome to U&L!  Can you provide an example *"a Qt desktop app"* with this problem?  Or is it all Qt desktop apps.  Having an example would be helpful for reproducing and maybe getting you a solution (or workaround, or explanation, etc.).  Thanks!

Comment: Hmmm. I tested with several open source Qt apps and they can all be resized. It seems specific to the proprietary app I am using. I will run some others tests and see if I can reproduce with another app. If not I will close that question.